# "Foi assim que a Alemanha perdeu a guerra", quando vergado para a frente de rabo para o ar . qual a origem desse ditado e seu verdadeiro significado?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica, ditados, história

"Foi assim que a Alemanha perdeu a guerra" qual a origem desse citado e seu verdadeiro significado ? Quando vergado para a frente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma pesquisa simples na internet por "origem de foi assim que a alemanha perdeu a guerra" deu-me logo este resultado do CiberDúvidas, que acho explica claramente:

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-expressao-foi-assim-que-a-alemanha-perdeu-a-guerra/20958

- Que a expressão se aplica a alguém com o rabo em posição elevada ou de igual forma desprotegida;
- E que terá tido inspiração na Alemanha ter perdido a Grande Guerra por ter sido "atacada por trás à bruta" pela Rússia.

---

Por "origem", suponho que queiras dizer "de onde veio esse sentido" e não "quando apareceu a expressão".

Comment: Aqui, a Grande Guerra, significa a I guerra Mundial?